# How to download txt azure blobs as plain text files?

Tags: c#, azure, text, download, azure-blob-storage

I have to download some txt files which are in a Azure container allowing anonymous access. I am working with Visual Studio 2017 and the program is a Windows Form application.

This is my code (where myUri is the string containing the Uri and myContainer the one for the Container):

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(myUri));
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(myContainer);

Azure.Pageable<BlobItem> blobs = container.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.All,BlobStates.All);
foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
{
       BlobClient bc = container.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
       bc.DownloadTo(new FileStream(path + blob.Name, FileMode.Create));
}
```

I can see the files in my local path with the correct names, the problem is that if I try to open the .txt(s) with a common editor such as Notepad++ I see encoded chars instead of normal ASCII.

Where is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may try to use a `StreamWriter` or any other API that supports specifying an Encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It looks like a binary file got uploaded with "txt" extension. I would recommend downloading files through a tool like Storage Explorer and check if indeed that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for comment)

While I am not able to see any issue in your code that would cause encoding issue, you may try the below to download your blob. Here I am using BlobDownloadInfo class to get an idea of the content type of what is being downloaded and it's Content.CopyTo method to write to the stream.

```
            Azure.Pageable<BlobItem> blobs = container.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.All, BlobStates.All);
            foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
            {

                BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
                BlobDownloadInfo download = blobClient.Download();
                Console.WriteLine("Content Type " + download.ContentType);
                using (FileStream downloadFileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(@"YourPath", blob.Name)))
                {
                    download.Content.CopyTo(downloadFileStream);
                    downloadFileStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code and it helped me at least to eliminate my doubts about the real content type, as the console always says "Content Type text/plain; charset=utf-8". In Notepad++ I still see strange chars .... but I am starting to think that it hasn't been my fault and probably I have to ask the client for some checks.

Comment: @Ludovico Ristori, if you check the file in the portal, will you see `strange chars` inn the file?